# Is there a way to have autocompletion for Spring Boot application.properties in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, spring-boot

I know that this functionnality exists in STS but I would like to know if there is any plugin or configuration to obtain this functionnality in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Since the STS is an Eclipse distribution with a bunch of Spring plugins, you can also install these plugins in any other Eclipse installation. To do that, just add their Update Site into your Eclipse and install the plugins. You can find the links for the Update Site at https://spring.io/tools/sts/all (update sites differ for Eclipse 4.4 and 4.5).

Additionally you can go to the Eclipse Marketplace and install all STS features from there (which will basically convert your Eclipse installation into STS).